# Relancer un client (recontact a customer about a quote for which no anwer was received)

Tags: word-request

1. In January, companyA asked companyB for a quote (request for proposal).
2. In February, companyB sent the proposal to companyA.
3. In March, no news.
4. In April, companyB recontacts companyA to find out what has happened with the quote, and whether it is a lost case, or just taking time.

How do you call step 4 in English?

In French, the verb would be "relancer le client".

Comment: Follow up on the proposal?

Comment: @oerkelens: Sounds good! Please post as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of focusing on the interaction with the client, you could describe what happens with the proposal / quote:

> Follow up on your proposal